# Rails skip_callback with if condition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have the line below in one of my models:

```
skip_callback :create, :after, :creation_email, if: -> { self.template_email }
```

`template_email` is a method in the model, that based on associated data will return true or false.  The method is returning `true`, but the callback is not being skipped.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 :

```
after_create :creation_email, if: :template_email #execute if true
after_create :creation_email, unless: :template_email #skip if true
```

Something this way it can be done.
Here **creation_email** is invoked when **template_email** method returns true otherwise skips invoking.

Comment: No, I want to SKIP only if it's true.  Using the above snippet DOESN'T SKIP if it's true.